# MySQL asynchronous database request performance

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking at asynchronous database requests in *PHP* using mysqlnd.  The code is working correctly but comparing performance pulling data from one reasonable sized table versus the same data split across multiple tables using asynchronous requests I'm not getting anything like the performance I would expect although it does seem fairly changeable according to hardware setup.

As I understand it I should be achieving, rather than:

```
x = a + b + c + d
```

Instead:

```
x = max(a, b, c, d)
```

Where `x` is the total time taken and `a` to `d` are the times for individual requests.  What I am actually seeing is a rather minor increase in performance on some setups and on others worse performance as if requests weren't asynchronous at all.  Any thoughts or experiences from others who may have worked with this and come across the same are welcome.

EDIT: Measuring the timings here, we are talking about queries spread over 10 tables, individually the queries take no more than around 8 seconds to complete, combining the time each individual request takes to complete (not asynchronously) it totals around 18 seconds.

Performing the same requests asynchronously total query time is also around 18 seconds.  So clearly the requests are not being executed in parallel against the database.

EDIT: Code used is exactly as shown in the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php)

```
<?php
$link1 = mysqli_connect();
$link1->query("SELECT 'test'", MYSQLI_ASYNC);
$all_links = array($link1);
$processed = 0;
do {
    $links = $errors = $reject = array();
    foreach ($all_links as $link) {
        $links[] = $errors[] = $reject[] = $link;
    }
    if (!mysqli_poll($links, $errors, $reject, 1)) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        if ($result = $link->reap_async_query()) {
            print_r($result->fetch_row());
            if (is_object($result))
                mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else die(sprintf("MySQLi Error: %s", mysqli_error($link)));
        $processed++;
    }
} while ($processed < count($all_links));
?>
```

Comment: How did you measure performance, what exactly did you expect and what code did you use to perform asynchronous database request in the first place? Async db communication won't yield any performance in majority of use cases of PHP (this has a lot to do with how the entire stack operates).

Comment: Implemented as per the PHP documentation, I expected close to what I describe above, `max(a, b, c, d)`.  'Async db communication won't yield any performance in majority of use cases' - can you explain this?

Comment: The idea behind asynchronous anything is that an event interface provided by the OS is used (`epoll`, `kqueue`, `IOCP`) so that CPU can be used for something while data is not there yet. While the data is being delivered between MySQL and PHP, what exactly is the rest of your code doing? Also, async data or sync data "delivery" still means that you will have the same amount of data delivered through the same unreliable network. Nothing can be faster there really. I can't see your code or SAPI that you use, but my comment is valid for majority of PHP use cases out there.

Comment: Not sure that applies here?  The use case here is splitting a single request that would normally be against one large database table instead across multiple tables containing part of the data each using multiple asynchronous requests.  Are you suggesting the bottleneck is not running the query against the data, rather getting the data to PHP?  Not sure that sounds feasible when we are talking about the same amount of data as with the single request against the larger table.

Comment: That use case scenario helps you gain no performance. What is the PHP engine doing while it waits for the data to arrive? Asynchronous approach, when done properly, lets each of the PHP processes do something else until the data arrives. What exactly are the processes doing until the data arrives? Also, it's not really true that you gained any performance with your setup. I suggest posting some code so we can take a better look and potentially help you gain performance you want. However, async MySQL reads won't speed anything up. They just let you use CPU a bit better.

Comment: Really don't agree with that actually.  While non blocking requests do allow you to process more lines of PHP while they are running, whats happening in this time is more requests are being made to the database with a new connection.  As MySQL natively handles requests in parallel the end result of this should be multiple database requests being performed in parallel and therefore all data being collected well before it would otherwise be with one large table as the size of split the tables are so much smaller.

Comment: That's fine, you don't have to agree with me but your assumptions are wrong. You haven't mentioned how you serve PHP (`mod_php`, `php-fpm`, `cli`). That alone has a huge impact on the performance and what happens in the background. Anyway, I wish you good luck, I will excuse myself from further discussion (no offense, but you seem like one of those tough guys who won't budge an inch) and I wish you all the luck and help you can get to resolve your issue.

Comment: No honestly, I'm not one of those guys - I really just want to understand what is stopping the requests from running in parallel and I don't feel like what you have said so far gives me that explanation.  If there are technical inaccuracies in what I have said then please do correct me - just at the moment you have given general reasons why you say requests can't happen in parallel, but not a technical explanation as to why, just vague issues which from what I know at the moment don't really stack up (in my head at least).

Comment: Can you show the PHP code?  How are you forking the process to parallelize the DB requests? Are you using any mysqlnd-related plugins (for example `PECL/mysqlnd_mc`)?

Comment: Edited post to add code in, it's exactly whats in the documentation, but with more queries, i.e. new connection for every request.  Not using an mysqlnd related plugins, should I be?

Answer (score 2):

I'll expand my comments and I'll try to explain why you won't gain any performance using the setup you have currently.

Asynchronous, in your case, means that the process of retrieving data is asynchronous compared to the rest of your code. The two moving parts (getting data) and working with the data are separate and are executed one after another, but only *when* the data arrives.

This implies that you want to utilize the CPU to its fullest, so you won't invoke PHP code until the data is ready.

In order for that to work, you must seize the control of PHP process and make it use one of operating system's event interfaces (`epoll` on Linux, or `IOCP` on Windows). Since PHP is either embedded into a web server (`mod_php`) or runs as its own standalone FCGI server (`php-fpm`), that implies the best utilization of asynchronous data fetching would be when you run a CLI php script since it's quite difficult to utilize event interfaces otherwise.

However, let's focus on your problem and why your code isn't faster.

You assumed that you are CPU bound and your solution was to retrieve data in chunks and process them that way - that's great, however since nothing you do yields faster execution, that means you are 100% I/O bound.

The process of retrieving data from databases forces the hard disk to perform seeking. No matter how much you "chunk" that, if the disk is slow and if the data is scattered around the disk - that part will be slow and creating more workers that deal with parts of the data will just make the system slower and slower since each worker will have the same problem with retrieving the data.

I'd conclude that your issue lies in the slow hard disk, too big of a data set that might be improperly constructed for chunked retrieval. I suggest updating this question or creating another question that will help you retrieve data faster and in a more optimal way.